# jquery methods on traversing the DOM

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have these structure:

```
<div class="brand">
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="" />
  <h4>Marca</h4>
  <p><span>+</span>licenses</p>
</div><!-- /.brand -->

<div class="license-details">
  <div class="collection-details">
    <h4>Wow</h4>
    <hr />
    <ul>
      <li>Collection</li>
      <li>Collection</li>
      <li>Collection</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collection-details">
    <h4>yay</h4>
    <hr />
    <ul>
      <li>Collection</li>
      <li>Collection</li>
      <li>Collection</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collection-details">
    <h4>yep</h4>
    <hr />
    <ul>
      <li>Collection</li>
      <li>Collection</li>
      <li>Collection</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Repeated for n times.
I want, with jQuery, to target the p tag of .brand div and show the relative .license-details div.

```
$(".brand p").on("click", function() {
  $(".license-details").fadeToggle(300);
});
```

This shows every .license-details div, but I want to show only the next .license-details div.

I tried:

```
$(".brand p").on("click", function() {
  $(this).next(".license-details").fadeToggle(300);
});
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get in to the parent element before using `next()`,

```
$(".brand p").on("click", function() {
    $(this).closest(".brand").next(".license-details").fadeToggle(300);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :  use `closest()` to get parent brand div and then use `next()` to get `license-details` div

```
$(".brand p").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('.brand').next(".license-details").fadeToggle(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong selector for targeting `.license-details` element. `.license-details` is sibling of p elements parents. use:

```
$(".brand p").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().next(".license-details").fadeToggle(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankushkk/8qnckocg/)

```
$(".brand p").on("click", function() {
  $(this).parent().next().fadeToggle(300);
});
```

Comment: @Ankush what if i want to hide(fadeDown) the other .license-details div showing only the .license-details div whose .brand div was clicked?